# How to run multiple web APIs from same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, project, solution

I'm trying to run multile Web APIs located in the same solution. One API i can acces with /client/1(project OtherApi) and the other API i call with /customer/1(project ConcurrentAPI). When i run the entire solution only /client/1 is giving me a response and when I try to call /customer/1 im getting an HTTP 404 error(look image).

[image]

I have already tried setting both projects as startup projects but this did not work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to run two processes that will listen to the same port.

I guess one of them will warn you that the port is busy.

So you may use different port in each solution, and then, access to each API using the appropriate port.